# Fastest way to convert strings to dates in R

Tags: r, fasttime

I would like to convert about 100 million dates in string form (eg: "09/20/2019") in `R`.

Doing

```
a = "09/20/2019"       
a <- as.Date(a, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

seems to be somewhat slow. Is there a faster way to achieve this conversion?

(Tried the `fasttime` package but it expects the following order: `year, month, day`... therefore the original string needs some further manipulations)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a lookup table approach (1) is 38x faster than `as.Date` for this example data.  Approach (2) is still 18x faster for this exammple data and is more convenient if you don't have a good way of generating `d`.  The particulars of your data will, of course, affect the speedup actually achieved.

```
# test data
set.seed(123)
d <- format(as.Date("2000-01-01") + 1:100, "%m/%d/%Y")
dd <- sample(d, 1000000, replace = TRUE)

# 1 - lookup table
system.time(as.Date(d, "%m/%d/%Y")[match(dd, d)])
##    user  system elapsed 
##    0.06    0.02    0.07 

# 2 - table lookup generating u on the fly instead of d
system.time({u <- unique(dd); as.Date(u, "%m/%d/%Y")[match(dd, u)] })
## user  system elapsed 
## 0.13    0.03    0.15 

# 3 - as.Date
system.time(as.Date(dd, "%m/%d/%Y"))
##    user  system elapsed 
##    2.61    0.07    2.67
```

Comment: The lookup table with `dd` sorted in advance should shave off a little time also

Answer (score 7):

Since you mentioned `fasttime`, I got curious about testing it against a few other common options. It requires dates in the year-month-day format, but you can do this with some regex.

I did benchmark testing on a smaller, but still cumbersome, set of dates. I'm on a year-old MacBook Pro with a ton of other stuff running, and still doing 100 trials on 1 million dates with all 3 methods finished before I was done eating a sandwich.

```r
set.seed(9)
days <- sample(1:30, 1e6, replace = TRUE)
date_str <- sprintf("09/%02d/2019", days)

# as.Date(date_str, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
# lubridate::mdy(date_str)
# fasttime::fastPOSIXct(gsub("^(\\d{2})/(\\d{2})/(\\d{4})", "\\3-\\1-\\2", date_str))

bench <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  list = list(
    base = as.Date(date_str, format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
    lubr = lubridate::mdy(date_str),
    fast = fasttime::fastPOSIXct(gsub("^(\\d{2})/(\\d{2})/(\\d{4})", "\\3-\\1-\\2", date_str))
  )
)

bench
#> Unit: nanoseconds
#>  expr min lq mean median uq max neval cld
#>  base   3  5 7.02      5  6 180   100   a
#>  lubr   4  5 6.91      6  6 148   100   a
#>  fast   4  5 8.77      5  6 332   100   a
```

Based on the mean and lowest maximum, `lubridate::mdy` runs the fastest without having to do any reformatting or specifying a format string. Based on median, the base `as.Date` run fastest but requires you setting the formatting string (not a big deal), or `fasttime` but with the regex stipulation. Make of that what you will.

I'd also note that `fasttime` converts to POSIX, so since there isn't a time element set it tacks one on—removing it might then become another time-consuming step.

Answer (score 6):

Using lubridate

```r
library(lubridate)
a = "09/20/2019"
mdy(a)
```

Comment: @joran it should be fast enough, I tested `mdy` on 1 million random dates, and it only took 0.22 seconds.

Comment: @joran it takes like 6 layers to get there but I think ultimately it's using `lubridate:::C_parse_dt` which could be faster than `as.Date` which uses the general-purpose `strptime`. I don't know enough about the C side to comment more fundamentally though